# Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler - Get current line number when compiling

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2010

i have a question about how to get the current line number while compiling of the VS C++ compiler, **IF** its possible of course.
I know its possible to use the LINE Macro from the preprocessor, but the results i get are not correct (well, at least not what i want).

Please tell me its possible :)

Thanks in advance

edit:
I think i found my mistake with using the `__LINE__` macro. I feel a kinda stupid now.. I think i have to go to bed (after some time you are not creating/adding anything new but destroying what you have done so far). Problem solved, thanks all for your help!

Comment: Why isn't `__LINE__` what you want?

Comment: The one thing that comes to mind in using `__LINE__` macro is to aid in debugging, the macro expands into a line number, so why would it not be correct? Do you mean to imply, that the binary executable with the `__LINE__` macro expanded and embedded is out of sync with the .C source?

Comment: Exactly. The problem is its REALLY out of sync. F.e. i get values that are higher than the total count of the source code lines (of course im referring to the count after the preprocessor is executed, in the .i file). Dont ask me why it happens, it just does happen..

Comment: @George: since VS 2010 is a **beta** compiler, it's entirely possible that you've stumbled upon a bug. Can you provide a simple example where it shows the wrong value?

Comment: @Evan: Good Point...The beta has been pushed back for another while hasn't it? +1 from me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok...to explain a bit better, as I think you have misunderstood the implications of the `__LINE__` macro...

Consider three source files:

```
/* Source1.c */
...list of headers & functions ....
if (!(fp = fopen("foo.blah", "r"))){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s @ line: %d: Could not open foo.blah\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}

/* Source2.c */
...list of headers & functions ....
if (!(p = (char *)malloc((10 * sizeof(char)) + 1)))){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s @ line: %d: Could not malloc\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}

/* Source3.c */
...list of headers & functions ....
if (!(ptr = (char *)malloc((50 * sizeof(char)) + 1)))){
   fprintf(stderr, "Error in %s @ line: %d: Could not malloc\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

Suppose those three files are compiled and linked into an executable called `foo.exe` and runtime errors appear, nitpicky aside, you would get:

```
Error in source2.c @ line 25: Could not malloc
Error in source1.c @ line 50: Could not open foo.blah
Error in source3.c @ line 33: Could not malloc
```

The total size of the project sources in terms of line count, **does not** mean that those lines are out of sync, regardless of what was pre-processed. I hope I have explained it somewhat easier for you to understand in aiding your reasoning behind the usage of the `__LINE__` macro.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.